# Conditional expectation of a random variable w.r.t a filtration generated by a Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, conditional-expectation

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $W=\big\{W(t):t\in[0,T]\big\}$ be a Brownian motion on it. Suppose $\big\{\mathcal{F}(t):t\in[0,T]\big\}$ be the filtration generated by $W$, i.e., $\mathcal{F}(t)=\sigma\{W(u), u\leq t\}$, for all $t\in[0,T]$. Consider a random variable $Z$ and define the process $Z(t):=\mathbb{E}[Z|\mathcal{F}(t)], t\in[0,T]$. Is this necessarily a continuous time process?

A stochastic process $\big\{X(t):t\in[0,T]\big\}$ is said to be a continuous time process if for each fixed $w\in\Omega$(good enough for almost every $w$ in $\Omega)$, the function $t\mapsto X(t)(w)$ is continuous.

Comment: It is well known that $Z(t)$ is a martingale with respect to $\mathcal F(t)$ if $\mathbb E[|Z|]<\infty$, but I don't see any reason to believe that $Z(t)$ would be a continuous-time process without further assumptions on $Z$.

Comment: Actually, I was wondering whether I can use Martingale Representation Theorem here. As a corollary to that theorem one can conclude that the process is continuous.

Comment: Yes, if $Z$ is integrable then the martingale $\Bbb E[Z\mid \mathcal F(t)]$, $0\le t\le T$ has a right-continuous version. And that version, by the MRT, is necessarily a.s. continuous.